# Comparing with a value which can be NULL

Tags: postgresql

The following expression

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = (SELECT MAX(a) FROM s)
```

returns nothing when the subquery returns NULL - even if there are NULLs in `t.a`.

I would like to return NULL values from t when the subquery returns NULL and non-NULL values from t if there are any matching the subquery.

Is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(MAX(a),0) FROM s` Try this

Comment: @JaydipJ, I thought about it, it isn't so clean, I need to use instead of 0 a value which I know isn't in s, there may be no such value at all.

Comment: @Evgeny So, what you're expecting   ?

Comment: _returns nothing when the subquery returns NULL - even if there are NULLs in t.a_ >  Because `IS` or `IS NOT` is the comparison operator for  `NULL` instead of `=` and `<>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y` is equivalent to `(x = y) OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL)`. So:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (SELECT MAX(a) FROM s)
```